# Nuget not restoring packages in visual studio 2015

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2015

I installed the `Visual Studio 2015` yesterday on my work machine and map a project from TFS that i was working on the previous version (VS 2013). All the projects in this solution are build on top of `.NET framework 4.5.1` . When i try to make a `Restore Nuget Packages` it says that all the packages in the `packages.config` files are downloaded already, but im getting a lot of compilation errors. The **Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;** reference for example, its declared on the `packages.config` file but im getting the 'red' error on the `using` clause of this reference in visual studio.

There´s other package that the nuget says it is installed but in the references its possible to see an yellow triangle. And this package is on the packages.config too.

Is that something different in this new versio of nuget?

Ps. I already installed the update of the nuget program.